# Do you know the key combination to get this screen? - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

One day, while we were playing on our w7 computer, we made a key combination that resulted on this screen (see image). Unfortunately we don't know what we did to get this. Can you please help us?

[image: W7 cool screen]

Comment: Bit of an odd thing to suspect but does the monitor come with any additional software? My dell comes with software that would turn windows into a nice snappable grid something like what you see there, but not with a shotcut.

Comment: In Windows 10, you don't need to do this any more. Just hit WinKey+Tab to open Task View and you'll see all the windows that are open.

Answer (score 6):

You can get that by right clicking on the Taskbar and selecting `Show windows side by side`.

[image: Side by Side]

To undo this, right click the Taskbar again and select `Undo Show side by side`.

[image]

Comment: I've had a pretty good look, but I can't find a key combo that will do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Does not exists a systemwide hotkey in Windows that performs that rearrange operation. An user click is needed on the taskbar as explained in @Michael Frank answer.

There is all the oficially keyboard shortcuts:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts#keyboard-shortcuts=windows-7

The logic to think what happened maybe is that you pressed a hotkey that activates a feature of a 3rd party app that does exactly that.